# Split arrays to fields and rows table - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have two arrays - first is field and second are values. I want to display as header table and I want to split the second array (data) by number of field.

My expected result:

```
field1    field2    field3
  1         1          1
  2         2          2
  3         3          3
  4         4          4
  5                    5

$field=['field1','field2','field3];
$data=['1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3','4','4','4','5','','5',];
```

This is what I tried:

```
<table style="width:100%;padding:15px;" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach($field as $item)
                <th style="padding:5px;">{{$item}}</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($data as $key=> $value)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$value}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any solution for these?

Comment: There's an error in your: $field=['field1','field2','field23'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert new row after 3 columns:

```
<tr>
@foreach($data as $key => $value)
    <td>{{ $value }}</td>
    @if (($key + 1) % 3 == 0)
    </tr>
    <tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [array-chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split your `$data` array to rows.

```
$field=['field1','field2','field3];
$data=['1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3','4','4','4','5','','5'];
$rows = array_chunk($data, count($field));
```

Now, when using HTML:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($rows as $row) // $row is array with 3 value - print it as you want
        <tr>
            @foreach($row as $val)
                <td>{{$val}}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use traditional way to achieve this like below.

```
<?php
$field = ['field1', 'field2', 'field23'];
$data  = ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '5', '', '5'];

?>
<table style="width:100%;padding:15px;" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach($field as $item)
                <th style="padding:5px;">{{$item}}</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($data as $key=> $value)
            @if($key == 0)
                <tr>
            @endif
                    <td>{{$value}}</td>
            @if(($key+1)%3 == 0)
                </tr>
                <tr>
            @endif
            @if(@key+1 == count($data))
                </tr>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Alternative:** By chunking data by count of fields

```
<?php
$field = ['field1', 'field2', 'field23'];
$data  = ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '5', '', '5'];
$temp = array_chunk($data, count($field));


?>
<table style="width:100%;padding:15px;" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach($field as $item)
                <th style="padding:5px;">{{$item}}</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @foreach($temp as $key => $value)
            <tr>
                @foreach($value as $v)
                    <td>{{$value}}</td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can also use for loop to display the data as follows.

```
<?php
@for($icount = 0; $icount <count($data); $icount = $icount + 3){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $data[$icount]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data[$icount+1]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data[$icount+2]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```